# Making a turn is choppy in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a pong game and first i wanna do movement...of the ball.
So it works going in a direction, but turning is a bit choppy. When you go right and then hold up and then release right it stops going up or right. Try going in a circle and you'll see.
How can i solve this and are there any other things that particularly suck about this piece code?

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
block_size = (32, 185)
pong_size = 20, 20
pong_pos_x = 390
pong_pos_y = 280

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption("aa")        
display = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))


while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

    display.fill(black)
    rekt = pygame.draw.rect(display, white, ((pong_pos_x, pong_pos_y), pong_size))
    pygame.display.update()
    h_move = 'none'
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    h_move = 'right'
            elif event.key == K_LEFT:
                    h_move= 'left'
            elif event.key == K_UP:
                    h_move = 'up'
            elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                    h_move = 'down'

    if h_move == 'right':
            pong_pos_x += 2
    elif h_move == 'left':
            pong_pos_x -= 2
    elif h_move == 'up':
            pong_pos_y -= 2
    elif h_move == 'down':
            pong_pos_y += 2


pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: you should use `lerp` or `slerp` to do rotation interpolation for more smooth movement and animation see : https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.lerp

Answer (score 2):

You should handle all your events in the loop. Right now its relying on the fact that some event drop out the bottom of the loop. Anytime you get any event other then `KEYDOWN` or `QUIT` you are stopping your movement.  This stopping is causing this jerkiness (especially the `KEYUP` event).

If you think about event sequence ... you are going up with `K_UP` in the down position, then you "turn". if you release the `K_UP` before pressing `K_LEFT` it will probably be okay (for a while).  But if you press `K_LEFT` before releasing `K_UP` you get the `KEWDOWN` `K_LEFT` then the `KEYUP` `K_UP` and your movement is stopped.

Maybe try something like this:

```
...
h_move = None

while True:
    # Event Loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key in (K_RIGHT, K_LEFT, K_UP, K_DOWN):
                h_move = event.key
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if h_move == event.key:
                h_move = None

    # Update State
    if h_move == K_RIGHT:
        pong_pos_x += 2
    elif h_move == K_LEFT:
        pong_pos_x -= 2
    elif h_move == K_UP:
        pong_pos_y -= 2
    elif h_move == K_DOWN:
        pong_pos_y += 2

    # Draw
    display.fill(black)
    rekt = pygame.draw.rect(display, white, ((pong_pos_x, pong_pos_y), pong_size))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Another thing you should do is limit your fps to a certain number of frames.  Since you are changing position by frames instead of time this could become a big factor.  I'd probably switch over to velocity and time for position changes instead of a static number each frame.